# Remove Read-only (Only applies to files and folders) attribute.

Tags: windows-10, file-permissions

I have a folder showing read only attributes. I am logged in as administrator. Tried unchecking the mark. Explorer shows "updating attributes", but when I check attributes again it has the read only check mark again. Ran cmd as an administrator and executed`attrib -r /s /d` to no avail. changing the owner to myself didn't help either. This is my folder with documents, and I don't have any of them open.

What can be locking files in read only state? How can I change that?

Comment: The problem is larger than I thought. All folders are now read only. Both existing and newly created. Regardless of the location. I will open a new question.

Comment: Sounds like you have a virus. https://www.google.com/search?q=read+only+virus

Comment: [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](http://superuser.com/q/100360)?